# How can I solve No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource in axios?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, axios, vue-component

My vue script like this :

```
<script>
export default {
    ...
    methods : {
        login() {
            // uri -> http://my-app.test/login?email=test@gmail.com&password=1234
            this.axios.get(uri).then((response) => {
                console.log(response)
                ...
            },
            ...
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

When login method executed, on the console exist error like this :

> Failed to load
>   http://my-app.test/login?email=test@gmail.com&password=1234: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8080' is therefore not allowed
>   access.

How can I solve the error?

Comment: @Quentin I still don't find an answer there

Comment: The answer is, make sure that the endpoint you are trying to reach is sending a fitting `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header

Comment: @Luca Kiebel I need a specific answer

Comment: Nope, you really don't. Answer these questions for yourself: What endpoint are you trying to reach? What headers should it send, but evidently isn't? What can you do about it?

Comment: @SuccessMan — If by "specific answer" you mean "a lump of code you can copy/paste" then we can't give that to you. We know nothing about the server side code generating the data you are requesting.

Comment: @Mihai — There's no need to answer in the comments. If you think you can provide a better answer than the ones on the duplicate question, then answer there. (Note that the OP has not mentioneed PHP anywhere in their question).

Answer (score -2):

You have to read about [CORS](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/) in order to understand how you can share resources between two websites.

Comment: @LucaKiebel I didn't know this. what are the rules for answer and comments?